# jTable not adding the whole data from Object defined - Java - Netbeans

Tags: java, arrays, object, netbeans, jtable

I have a button in which after pressing it, the items that are in critical level will populate the jTable. I have managed to do it but the issue i'm facing is that the row it adds just populates the first column and leave the rest blank. My questions are, how come it only populates the first column and how do I get the rest of the columns filled?

PS. The table columns are PRODUCT NAME - STOCK ON HAND - MINIMUM QTY
yet, the first column shows the stockOnHand not even the productName.

Below are my codes for the button:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tableMinimum.getModel(); 
try{
  String viewCriticalSQL = "Select * from tblProduct";
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(viewCriticalSQL);
  rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
  while(model.getRowCount()>0){
   model.removeRow(0);
  }
while(rs.next()){
  String prodName = rs.getString("productName");
  int getStock = rs.getInt("stockOnHand");
  int getMinimum = rs.getInt("minimumOrder");
  if (getStock<getMinimum){
   Object[] adRow = {prodName, getStock, getMinimum};
   model.addRow(adRow);
   }
   }
}catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Use `model.setRowCount(0)` to clear the model more efficiently

Comment: Great! Thanks! Any idea about the other one? On why it only populates the first column and why just the stockOnHand?